# Prestashop PayPal Error

Tags: paypal, prestashop, paypal-sandbox, braintree, prestashop-1.7

I'm trying to add PayPal payments in a Prestashop (v1.7.3) store using the [PayPal & Braintree Official Module](https://addons.prestashop.com/en/payment-card-wallet/1748-paypal-braintree-official.html) (v3.11.6), but until now without success.

Installed and configured the module without any problems, but every time i proceed with a payment this error is displayed to the user:

[image]

Tested the module in both sandbox and production environments, and the error still persists.

What can be the problem?

**UPDATE:** After some debugging i found the origin of the problem. The problem is that the module is unable to connect to PayPal's API via cURL with SSL/TLS.
I'm using Prestashop in Windows Server with IIS, and in this environment cURL has to be informed where the certificate authority is located in order to establish a secure connection. 
I downloaded the cacert.pem file from [curl website](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html), stored it in my server and then, in module files (PPHtmlConfig.php) i added the CA location in the cURL options settings manually:

```
CURLOPT_CAINFO => 'C:\\(...)\\cacert.pem',
```

Now i'm able to connect to PayPal's API and successfully make a payment!

I've contacted the module's tech support team and they are analysing this issue.

Comment: Can you confirm you have SSL configured correctly? Per the [Module's  docs](https://addons.prestashop.com/en/payment-card-wallet/1748-paypal-braintree-official.html?pab=1&)- *For security reasons, you need to make sure that you're using TLS 1.2 or above, SHA-256 signed 2048-bit in order to do API calls to PayPal.*

Comment: @hollabaq i think so, but to be sure i'm going to contact my service provier. I'll get back to you with feedback.

Comment: @hollabaq the problem is related with that. The module isn't able to establish a secure connection. I've updated my question with further information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several contacts with the module tech support, this is their final response to the issue:

> We do not know the specialty of your server. This is not a recurring
>   error in our module. It happens if the CURL can not find the CA
>   certificate. In general, we advise you to ask your server to verify
>   that the CA certificate is correctly configured. Otherwise, it is
>   necessary to specify the route or curl to find the certificate, for
>   example, as you did in your module.
>
> At the moment there is no way to specify this in our module in
>   general. So, you should wait for the next update of our Paypal module.

So, if someone comes across the same issue when using a Windows Server environment, specify the complete CA path in the module files (as explained in the question update):

> I downloaded the cacert.pem file from curl website, stored it in my
>   server and then, in module files (PPHtmlConfig.php) i added the CA
>   location in the cURL options settings manually:

```
CURLOPT_CAINFO => 'C:\\(...)\\cacert.pem',
```